# How to SUM COUNTIFS for items not in array in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have columns that have a "yes", "no", or something else.  I'd like to count all the cells that do NOT have a "yes" or "no".  I've tried `=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:G2,NOT({"yes","no"})))` and `=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:G2,{"<>yes","<>no"}))` but the first doesn't work at all and the second rsults in 8 (double what I'd have without the <>).

Here's a sample of my data:

```
|1  |2  |2  |4    |5 |6  |
|Yes|No |   |Other|NO|YES|
```

If the formula is in row 2, the result wuld be 2.  What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the positive from the whole:

```
=COLUMNS(B2:G2)-SUM(COUNTIF(B2:G2,{"yes","no"}))
```

[image]